# sails-mysql not return chinese characters properly

Tags: mysqli, sails.js

I'm using the following to query mysql table and there's field I've chinese chars in it. If I use php mysqli to query it then it will return chinese characters correctly without doing anything or convert. Any idea?

I even set the following for the sails-mysql seems not help.

```
charset   : 'utf8',
collation : 'utf8-general-ci'
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql

Comment: here are some other sails.js devs here that you can chat with. See if they can help. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in utf8-general-ci try

```
charset   : 'utf8',
collation : 'utf8_general_ci'
```